# jQuery scroll fails for iframe (firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot get scroll to work, here is the complete stuff: 
http://zed.mit.edu/scroll2/buc.php

I'm trying to refresh the page while maintaining the scroll position of the iframe inside.

I'd like to have an alert when I actively scroll the iframe, these two both fail:

```
$(top).frames['#iframe_bucinid'].scroll(function() ....

$('#iframe_bucinid').scroll(function() ...
```

The page's iframe is defined as:

```
<iframe class="inframe" src="bucin.php" name="bucin" id="iframe_bucinid">
```

Notice that getting the scrollTop works with

```
top.frames['bucin'].document.body.scrollTop
```

Comment: Have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930779/jquery-iframe-scroll-event-ie)

Answer (score 1):

I had success (Chrome and Firefox) in doing what you're asking using the following code:

`$('#iframe_bucinid').contents().scroll(function() { 
    alert('hello'); 
});`

The key difference between your code and mine being the `contents()` part.

Be sure to test this thoroughly though, you might run into problems in some browsers due to silly implementations of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).