# Image vanish on iframe scroll

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the code:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#arrow').show()('TOP!');
    }
    else {
        $('#arrow').hide()($(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

This allows me to have an image that disappears when i start scrolling and reappear when the scroll bar hits the top of the page.. But.

I was wondering if it was possible to link this JS to an iframe on my page and get the image to disappear when I scroll using the iframe?

Comment: You cannot alter anything within an iframe, it's a security feature.

Comment: I don't want to alter the content of an iframe, I just want my code to recognise when I scroll using the iframe and alter an image on MY page

Comment: You will have to change code in the iframe content, if you have access to that. Then use `window.parent` to do what you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent

Comment: sorry I was wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930779/jquery-iframe-scroll-event-ie apparently it's do-able

Comment: Thank you so much for finding that it is possible but I'm unsure how to apply it as I'm no good at JS. My image ID that I want to disappear is #marker and my iframe is #productsearch. How would I apply them?